# MultiTriggers using the same property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, multitrigger

I'm actually overriding the default `ControlTemplate` of the `TextBox` and in order to do what I want, I need to trigger two animations when the `TextBox` loose the focus and it's text is empty. In order to do that I'm using a `MultiTrigger` with two conditions like this:

(I'll use an animation on the `FontSize` for the example)

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
    <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Title" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" From="9" To="120" Duration="0:0:2">
          <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
          </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
      </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

The thing is that, the animation is triggered at the `TextBox` instantiation because the `TextBox` is not focused and the `Text` is empty.
So we can say that the animation and the `MultiTrigger` are working, but when I focus the `TextBox` once (the `GotFocus` resets the `FontSize`), on the `LostFocus` the animation is not triggered anymore.

**BUT** if I replace the whole `MultiTrigger.EnterActions` by this:

```
<MultiTrigger.Setters>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</MultiTrigger.Setters>
```

Everything is working like a charm. I mean that the background is red at the begining, white on the `GotFocus` and red again on the `LostFocus`.

I might by misunderstanding the way we have to use the `EnterActions` but there's not that much documentation on `MultiTriggers` out there. Do you know why the animation isn't triggered anymore after the first time?

And by the way, is there a better way than `Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"`to check if the `Text` property is empty?

**EDIT :**
In my `ControlTemplate.Triggers` I'm already using two `EventTriggers`, one is routed to the `GotFocus` event and the other one to the `LostFocus` event.
I saw on the MSDN that [`EnterActions` does not apply to the EventTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DFR-FR%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.TriggerBase.EnterActions);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2), so I tried to get rid of both of my `EventTriggers` and now it works.

The thing is that I used a `MultiTrigger` because I needed to check if the `Text` was empty on the `LostFocus` but may be there is a way to put that condition in an `EventTrigger`?

**EDIT #2:**
AS @Satish Pai asked, here is the full `ControlTemplate` in which I replaced the `EventTriggers` by a `MutliTrigger` because, as I said, they seems to be incompatible.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="14"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" Margin="8,14,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"></TextBlock>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="UnfocusedUnderLine" Fill="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}" Height="6" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="UnderLine" Fill="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}" Height="6" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Width="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger x:Name="FocusChanged">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions> <!--GotFocus-->
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!--Change UnderLine Color-->
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnderLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="500" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                    
                    <!--Move Title Up-->
                    <ThicknessAnimation From="8,14,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="Title" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" AutoReverse="False" >
                        <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </ThicknessAnimation>
                    
                    <!--Decrease Title Size-->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                     From="12"
                                     To="9"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.25">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>  <!--LostFocus-->
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    
                    <!--Change UnderLine Color-->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnderLine"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="500"
                                     To="0"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.2">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger x:Name="LostFocusAndEmptyText">
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!--Move Title Down-->
                    <ThicknessAnimation From="0,0,0,0" To="8,14,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Title" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" AutoReverse="False" >
                        <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </ThicknessAnimation>

                    <!--Increase Title Size-->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                     From="9"
                                     To="12"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.2">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <!--LostFocusWithEmptyText-->
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The thing is that both of the `MultiTiggers` are referring to the same `IsFocused` property and they don't wanna work together. If I delete the `LostFocusAndEmptyText` trigger it works, but I really need to differentiate the case where I loose the focus with an empty text and without.

Any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: Could you please also provide the whole xaml including the  `ControlTemplate`

Comment: Instead of using the exit actions, why don't you use 3 triggers? single: IsKeyboardFocusWithin=true, single: IsKeyboardFocusWithin=false and multi: IsKeyboardFocusWithin=false+Text.Length=0?

Answer (score 0):

Chage your TiTle TextBlock init state. Marging="0,0,0,0" FontSize = "9"

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" FontSize="9" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
```

use Animation's property 'FillBehavior' set to "Stop". and
remove animation's property 'From' in EventTrigger.
good luck!

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation To="0,0,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Title" FillBehavior="Stop" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" AutoReverse="False" >
                    <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </ThicknessAnimation>

                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" FillBehavior="Stop" 
                                To="9"
                                Duration="0:0:0.25">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger x:Name="LostFocusAndEmptyText">
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter TargetName="Title"  Property="FontSize"  Value="12"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Title"  Property="Margin"  Value="8,14,0,0"/>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation From="0,0,0,0" To="8,14,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.25" 
                                        FillBehavior="Stop"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Title" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                        AutoReverse="False" >
                        <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </ThicknessAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Title"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                To="12" From="9"
                                Duration="0:0:0.2">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    </MultiTrigger>                        
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```